# How to get NSAccessibilityChildren

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, accessibility

I'm trying to get an array of the children of an `AXUIElement` with `NSAccessibilityChildrenAttribute` in order to build a tree of all `AXUIElement` in an application.

It works fine on Mac native applications but not on java applications (like NetBeans).

When I get an `AXUIElement` with `AXUIElementCopyElementAtPosition (AXUIElementRef application, float x,float y, AXUIElementRef *element)`, I can retrieve all the parents by going back to the root, but I can't get the children.

Is there an other way to access the children ?

Answer (score 3):

```
import Foundation
import AppKit
import ApplicationServices

let indd = NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications.filter{$0.bundleIdentifier == "com.adobe.InDesign"}.first!
indd.activate(options: .activateIgnoringOtherApps)
let app = AXUIElementCreateApplication(indd.processIdentifier)
var attArray:CFArray?
AXUIElementCopyAttributeNames(app, &attArray)
print(attArray ?? "nil")
var childrenPtr:CFTypeRef?
AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(app, kAXChildrenAttribute as CFString, &childrenPtr)
let children = childrenPtr as! CFArray
print(children)
```

The CFArray contains the children of the parent application.  The same principle can be repeated recursively.

The above code should look similar in Obj-C.  I copy pasted this from my workspace.

The key answer to your question is the

```
AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(app, kAXChildrenAttribute as CFString, &childrenPtr)
```

As children are in this model an attribute of the parent.